# List<Diary_Entry> DiaryEntry cant convert to collections.generic.list

Tags: asp.net, linq, list

```
List<Diary_Entry> DiaryEntry = new List<Diary_Entry>();

DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
    where DE.Site_Id == 1
    && DE.Date == tempDate
    select DE).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

ERROR:cannot implicity convert type `Diary_Entry` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Diary_Entry>`

Can some one please advise how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `FirstOrDefault()` call. That returns a single entity and your `DiaryEntry` instance is a list. It should either be this (`DiaryEntry` will be of type `List<Diary_Entry>`):

```
var DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                  where DE.Site_Id == 1
                  && DE.Date == tempDate
                  select DE).ToList();
```

Or it should be this (`DiaryEntry` will be of type `Diary_Entry`):

```
var DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                  where DE.Site_Id == 1
                  && DE.Date == tempDate
                  select DE).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable DiaryEntry is of type List but you try to set it equal to variable of Diary_Entry type. You should use

```
List<Diary_Entry> DiaryEntry = new List<Diary_Entry>();
DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                      where DE.Site_Id == 1
                      && DE.Date == tempDate
                      select DE).ToList();
```

This query returns list of values of type Diary_Entry. If you want to get single value of type Diary_Entry you should use

```
 var DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                          where DE.Site_Id == 1
                          && DE.Date == tempDate
                          select DE).FirstOrDefault();
```

in this query you should not use `ToList()`.